# Is it possible to teleport as an Anivia egg?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was in game against an Anivia, and someone on my team told him that he should have taken teleport so he could TP in egg form. Can this actually happen?

Comment: I looked for Rebirth (Anivia's egg passive) here http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Patch but could not find. I belive the patch is about the Teleport summoner spell. But is not possible anymore, not before become egg(correct few month ago), not while egg(correct a lot of months ago). I didn't post as answer, because I could not find the patch change.

Answer (score 5):

This was an old bug. Anivia at one point could teleport when she was in egg form, as far as I know, it is no longer possible. If you see someone do it in game, I would fill out a bug report :)

Answer (score 2):

If Anivia begins channeling Teleport, and isn't CC'ed, she will be teleported at the end of the channel duration. This still occurs if Anivia loses all of her health and becomes Eggnivia, which despite not being able to use summoner spells, will still be teleported if the channel wasn't interrupted

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible anymore (it used to be a bug). Your summoners are blocked out as if you were dead.